# How to hide or exclude fields in strapi query?

Tags: strapi

I get all the properties in query, like even created_by,updated_by...

```
{
"client_ip": "Velit quo libero sun",
"verifier": "Voluptas ut sit sun",
"created_by": {
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "admin",
    "lastname": "admin",
    "username": null
},
"updated_by": {
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "admin",
    "lastname": "admin",
    "username": null
}}
```

Is there a way to remove these unwanted fields?

Answer (score 3):

There are two thing you could do in the model and attributes validation

1. Use the `private` validation options on an attribute, to not return it in the default endpoints.

```json
  "attributes": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "private": true
  }
```

Check out [the docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/models.html#validations).

2. You can also disable the timestamps in your model, with:

```json
{
  "options": {
    "timestamps": false
  }
}
```

Check out [the docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/models.html#model-options).

Something like the 2nd method, will soon be available for the created_by & updated_by attributes, it is [a know issue](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/7177) since `v3.1.x`.

Comment: I am aware of the private field. I just want to get rid of the created_by and updated_by

Comment: As in the known linked issue and the GitHub [issue](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/7944) (I assume) you created. It isn't possible yet. In v3.2.0 it will probably be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

if you dont want to show this attributes do this on model..

```
 "options": {
    "privateAttributes": [
      "createdAt",
      "updatedAt",
      "publishedAt",
      "createdBy",
      "updatedBy"
    ]
```

and if you dont want to show your columns data Then do this.

```
await strapi.entityService.findMany('modelNAme', {
        fields:['fieldName'] }.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [custom controller](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html) to reduce payload size or hide responses manually.

In your controller handler you can use the [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator to remove unwanted props
Using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (?) (supported from Node.js version 14)

```js
handlerName : async (ctx) => {
  const results = await strapi.services?.["serviceName"]?.findOne() ?? {};
  delete results?.created_by;
  delete results?.updated_by;
  ctx.send(results)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use strapi >= 4.0.0, you can provide `privateAttributes` to your model's options to exclude fields from both the admin panel and the response. https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/models.html#model-options